# How to access dynamodb generated by graphql model in lambda function and perform operations?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, graphql, amazon-dynamodb

I am very new to aws and I am having a hard time understanding the process between lambda function and the dynamoDB. I followed this [documentation](https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/usage/lambda-triggers/#as-a-part-of-the-graphql-api-types-with-model-annotation).

According to the documentaion this trigger is used to get the records of the tables from dynamodb.

```
exports.handler = function (event, context) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(event, null, 2));
  event.Records.forEach((record) => {
    console.log(record.eventID);
    console.log(record.eventName);
    console.log('DynamoDB Record: %j', record.dynamodb);
  });
  context.done(null, 'Successfully processed DynamoDB record');
};
```

And the event is coming from the 'event.json' file. Which is this:

```
{
  "key1": "value1",
  "key2": "value2",
  "key3": "value3"
}
```

What I want to accomplished is to retrieve and update the data of my dynamodb 'User' table which is from this graphql model.

```
type User @model @auth(rules: [{allow: owner, operations: [create, update]}]){
    id: ID!
    coins: Int
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure amplify docs is the best one to use for learning Lambda. Second, why do you want to use GraphQL to perform CRUD operations on an Amazon DynamoDB table  from within a Lambda function. There are other ways such as using the JavaScript SDK from within a Lambda function as discussed here in the **JavaScript Developer Guide**:

[Creating scheduled events to execute AWS Lambda functions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v3/developer-guide/scheduled-events-invoking-lambda-example.html)

Comment: The reason why I want to use GraphQL to perform CRUD operations on an Amazon DynamoDB table from within a Lambda function is because I am using it in android application. I am doing this for better security incase my app gets reverse engineered.

Comment: Is your Android app invoking the Lambda function?  If how are you planning on doing this?

Comment: I am planning to call the lambda function using the rest api and then perform the operation of dynamodb inside the lambda function.

Comment: Then you can still use a Service Client within a Lambda Function (ie - JS SDK) without fear of someone reserve eng your Android app to get your Service creds. That is, you can invoke the Lambda function using Restful manner (does not need Service Client) and then use a Service Client within Lambda that no one will be able to reverse Eng.

Comment: Can you please teach me how am I able to do that? Or at least give me some links on doing it? I am really new to lambda, serverless backend and restful apis.

Comment: As a starting point - go through the above link. It will teach you how to create an AWS Lambda function that can invoke Amazon DynamoDB operations using the AWS SDK for JavaScript (which as a standard way to write Lambda functions).  Then you can use AWS Gateway to expose the Lambda function as a Restful endpoint

Comment: See this too - it will teach you  how to use  Amazon API Gateway to invoke AWS Lambda functions. -- https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/main/javascriptv3/example_code/cross-services/lambda-api-gateway

Comment: Is it okay instead of using javascript, I use node.js?

Comment: You can do that

Comment: Okay okay thank you!